# Can't load instafeed.min.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, instagram, instafeedjs

I'm trying to add the instaFeed on my web app but I got this error:

> instafeed.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I think it's because I don't add correctly the script but yeah I can't find what's wrong :
[image]

And in my Javascript I create a feed like this when I click on a button:

```
 'click #goToInstagramFeed'(event){
    setTimeout(function(){
      var feed = new Instafeed({
          get: 'tagged',
          tagName: 'awesome',
          clientId: 'myId'
      });
      console.log("dans le script");
      feed.run();
      window.scrollTo(0,200);
    }, 5000)
 }
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to load it from a CDN instead? Your local copy of instafeed might be corrupted.

Comment: Hmm where can I get the CDN ? because I used [link](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js)

Comment: Nvm, instafeed's devs themselves use the local path in their examples. Didn't really looked into it before posting my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script tags do not work when placed inside Blaze template. In Meteor to use 3rd party JS library, you could either:

- Install them via NPM, then import and use them where needed
- If there are cdn links available, you could include them in the `<head>` or `<body>` tag
- If you only have the .js files of the libraries, then you could place them under `client/compatibility` folder so that they will be bundled automatically

Comment: Oh thank you I choosed the 3th option, now I have an other error (Uncaught Error: Error from Instagram: The access_token provided is invalid.) but I'll search for it. Thanks for the help !